# How to apply cors in rest webservice for different domain

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created one rest webservice in c#. I have stored some domains in table and i want that my application will work only if the requesting url is exist in the domain. How can i achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: You did it with Asp.net Mvc Web api, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the request host name to check it in db. For example:

```
var host = Request.RequestUri.Host;
var exist = yourContext.yourTableSet.Any(p=>p.Host == host);
if(exist)
{
    //do something
}
else { //... }
```

but, if you have (for example) some reseller, you can use the [Multi Tenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) in your project.